# How 0X00020000 get converted to 131072?

Tags: java

I am performing some bit wise operations(& and |) on hexadecimal numbers.

```
Integer number1 = 0X00020000;
Integer number2 = 0X00000001;

System.out.println(number1);
System.out.println(number1 | number2);
System.out.println(number1 + number2);

Output :
131072
131073
131073
```

0X00020000 automatically got converted to 131072.

I am getting right answer but I am curious to know how & **WHY Java converts hexadecimal number to decimal number.**

I know how to convert hexadecimal number to decimal number.

0X00020000 will be converted to decimal as follows,

```
(2 X 16^4) + (0 X 16^3) + (0 X 16^2) + (0 X 16^1) + (0 X 16^0)
= (2 X 65536) + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0
= 131072
```

Comment: Java doesn't convert anything, 0x20000 is just another representation for the exact same number. You can replace the hexadecimal numbers in your code with their decimal counterparts and you will get the exact same result.

Comment: Why? It has the `0x` prefix.

Comment: Is the question why it doesn't get printed out in its hexadecimal representation?

Comment: look for method `Integer.toString()`, always when you don't understand why was printed smth, look `toString()` method of class.

Comment: binary or hex format is more nature to computer itself, decimal format is for human who has 10 fingers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right way to look at this is not as something being converted, but rather the way something is being *displayed*.

There is only one value stored for the variable, no matter how to write it in your source code. Write it anyway you like; once it is stored in memory, Java neither knows or cares what it looked like in your source code.

`System.out.println` renders the integer value, as a string, using decimal by default. Try `System.out.printf("%x\n", number1);` to see it rendered in hex.

Just keep in mind there is a big difference between the integer value and its string representation. If there is anything "converted" here, it's a conversion from an string (in your source) to an integer value (represented in memory) to a string (written to standard output).  The last step uses decimal numerals by default.

Comment: System.out.printf("%x\n", number1);  gives MissingArgumentException       System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(number1));  prints 20000

Comment: Shouldn't.  See http://ideone.com/1srVpz to see `printf` working. Your ways works too; they are both fine.

Comment: Oh Sorry Ray Toal!!   I used + instead of comma(,).    System.out.printf("%x\n", number1);  works fine.     System.out.printf("%x\n"    + number1);  throws MissingArgumentException.   That was my mistake.